# Avoid re-render in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, rerender

I'm trying to develop a drag and drop game by using React Native.
The game is something like when you drag and drop the item to the target place, it will disappear, and something will happen on the target place, let make it easy to discuss, let's say the background colour of the target place will change.
Actually it works, but my problem is that, after every drop, the screen will re-render, if there are just texts on the screen, we won't find it, but when I replace the text with some images, it looks like the screen flickers after a drop.

To make the code short and easy to discuss, I'll put a prototype here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, PanResponder, Animated } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const pan = useState(new Animated.ValueXY())[0];
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
  const BLUE_BOX_POSITION = {
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
  }
  const BLUE_BOX_SIZE = 120;
  const RED_CIRCLE_SIZE = 100;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isVisible);
  }, [isVisible]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('render');
  });

  const panResponder = useState(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        console.log("onPanResponderGrant");
        pan.setOffset({
          x: pan.x._value,
          y: pan.y._value,
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event( [null, {
        dx: pan.x,
        dy: pan.y,
      }], {useNativeDriver: false}),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
        const {x, y} = pan.__getValue();
        if (
          x > BLUE_BOX_POSITION.x &&
          x + RED_CIRCLE_SIZE < BLUE_BOX_POSITION.x + BLUE_BOX_SIZE &&
          y > BLUE_BOX_POSITION.y &&
          y + RED_CIRCLE_SIZE < BLUE_BOX_POSITION.y + BLUE_BOX_SIZE
        )
        {
          setIsVisible(false);
        } else {
          pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
        }
        console.log("onPanResponderRelease");
      },
    })
  )[0];

  console.log(panResponder);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {isVisible && (
        <Animated.View
          style={{
              transform: pan.getTranslateTransform(),
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              borderRadius: 50,
            }}
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        />
      )}
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: BLUE_BOX_POSITION.x,
          top: BLUE_BOX_POSITION.y,
          width: 120,
          height: 120,
          backgroundColor: isVisible ?  "blue" : "red",
          opacity: 0.5,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I think the re-rendering is because of the useState hook, and tried to use useRef to replace it, it won't re-render anymore, but I can't find the actions what I expected neither.

Is there a way to make things act as what I want and avoid the re-render or flicker things at the same time.

Thanks in advance!